# How to link to a specific page when two pages have the same title

Tags: roadkill-wiki

How to link to a specific page when two pages have the same title? Is there a way to do that?
Or can I have the title named something but link to that page via the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the full url of the page, e.g. http://demo.roadkillwiki.net/wiki/12223/ - but otherwise you will need to name the pages slightly different, e.g. add a 1 or 2 to the title.

Comment: Yeah I've learned that from playing around with the system more. Thanks for the feedback :)